# ¿ Como y donde debo poner los parámetros para las cookies?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

Hola estoy tratando de crear el código que controlan el tiempo de validez de una sesion
 , para que el navegador recuerde la web y no tenga que cargarla cada vez que la recargo, pero eso  no di en un curso que hice.
He buscado información al respecto y con el código que cree veo que el navegador no recuerda la web.
He leído algo sobre los parámetros `expires` y `max-age`, pero no se ni como ni donde debo de colocarlas.
Muestro lo conseguido hasta ahora, pero que no hace la función que esperaba para que el navegador recuerde mi web.
Si pueden ayudarme, hay algún sitio donde pueda encontrar la forma de aprender a escribir el código y donde ponerlo, o explicarme como debo proceder. También me sugirieron que busque documentación de localStorage es nativo JS, pero he buscado y con lo que vi, no soy capaz de crear el código para conseguir que los navegadores recuerden la web.  La cosa es que tarda mucho en cargar, y ya corregí los errores que tenia que hacia que fuera lenta. Y por mas que la abro una y otra vez, me vuelve a mostrar el mensaje de cookies y carga todo desde nuevo
Gracias.

```js
function getCookie(c_name) {
      var c_value = document.cookie;
      var c_start = c_value.indexOf(" " + c_name + "=");
      if (c_start == -1) {
        c_start = c_value.indexOf(c_name + "=");
      }
      if (c_start == -1) {
        c_value = null;
      } else {
        c_start = c_value.indexOf("=", c_start) + 1;
        var c_end = c_value.indexOf(";", c_start);
        if (c_end == -1) {
          c_end = c_value.length;
        }
        c_value = unescape(c_value.substring(c_start, c_end));
      }
      return c_value;
    }

    function setCookie(c_name, value, exdays) {
      var exdate = new Date();
      exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
      var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
      document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
    }

    if (getCookie('tiendaaviso') != "1") {
      document.getElementById("cookies").style.display = "block";
    }
    function PonerCookie() {
      setCookie('tiendaaviso', '1', 365);
      document.getElementById("cookies").style.display = "none";
    }
```

```css
#cookies {
 background-color: #333;
 display:none;
 position:fixed;
 left:0px;
 right:0px;
 bottom:0px;
 padding-bottom:60px;
 width:100%;
 text-align:center;
 min-height:40px;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 color:#fff;
 z-index:99999;
}

.inner {
 width:100%;
 position:absolute;
 padding-left:5px;
 font-family:verdana;
 font-size:12px;
 top:30%;
}

.inner a.ok {padding:4px;color:#00ff2e;text-decoration:none;}
.inner a.info {padding-left:5px;text-decoration:none;color:#faff00;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
<title>cokies</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="cookies">
    <div class="inner">
      Esta web utiliza cookies como datos estad&iacute;sticos de su navegaci&oacute;
      Si contin&uacute;a navegando consideramos que acepta el uso de cookies.
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="ok" onclick="PonerCookie();">
        <b>OK</b>
      </a> |
      <a href="politica-cookies.html" target="_blank" class="info">M&aacute;s informaci&oacute;n</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Estoy intentado entender lo que quieres hacer pero por mas que leo no lo consigo, el titulo de la pregunta no tiene nada que ver con lo que explicas, ademas a que te refieres con "**el navegador recuerde mi WEB**"? y, siempre que recargas la pagina con `F5` esta se recargara y no podrás evitarlo. Trata de detallar mejor lo que quieres y tal vez alguien pueda ayudarte.

Comment: Pues quiero crear el código necesario para  cookies que almacenen mi web en el navegador y no tenga que cargarla entera cada vez que entro en ella, no se que no entiendes o que mas debo explicar.

Comment: que errores te da en la consola? (presiona F12 en chrome)

Comment: La consola no me da errores relacionados con esto, me da errores de:  Slow network is detected. See <URL> for more details. Fallback font will be used while loading: <URL> pero no me da ninguno de los cookies. La cosa es que tarda mucho en cargar, y ya corrigi los errores que tenia que hacia que fuera lenta. Y por mas que la abro una y otra vez, me vuelve a mostrar el mensaje de cookies y carga todo desde nuevo

Comment: las cookies tienen un parámetro extra llamado path que depende de la ruta de la pagina, es la misma pagina que no lee la cookie? o es otra pagina que esta en otra ruta ? ej: /index.html y /productos/index.html

Comment: también en la consola puedes probar las funciones y ver que funcionen (setCookie y getCookie). para ver si esta guardando algo en el mismo f12 vas a la pestaña aplicacion y a la izquierda tienes storage->cookies

Comment: Ya probe, y no me sale ninguna cookie, solo la de mi pagina

Comment: Por una de esas casualidades, ¿no estarás haciendo las pruebas offline? Es decir, las cookies son un mecanismo HTTP y no funcionan con el protocolo file:///

Comment: Gracias @RobertoVaccaro tengo el código que se ve hay, y como digo con a web en el servidor, al recargar vuelve a cargar la pagina de nuevo, mostrando el mensaje de cookies de nuevo. Si pido ayuda es porque no se como colocar ni donde el código de las cokiees, ni que código debo poner. Gracias

Comment: Ahí te expandí el ejemplo para editar los archivos de tu web, si ves que se complica avisa hasta donde llegaste y lo vemos. Recuerda hacer copia de seguridad de los archivos que modifiques.

Comment: @gemita entiendo haces un sitio web, mencionas sesión... pero que tecnologías adicionales a html/css/js estás usando para tu sitio, en que tipo de servidor estás publicando tu página? pareciera que tu problema es de caché y no de una sesión como tal, menos de cookies, pero no tengo la seguridad por que no me es tan claro si usas o no una tecnología de servidor

Comment: Gracias @JonnathanQ , no uso ninguna tecnología mas que las herramientas html, css, javascript. Tengo la web alojada en un servidor de hostinger sin mas que mi código, sin tecnología alguna. Quizá el problema se a de cache como dices, y que no se almacena, por lo que debe recargar cada vez que inicio la pagina¡na...

Comment: @gemita Si no usas ninguna tecnología servidor, entonces no podemos hablar de una sesión, por otra parte tampoco es un tema de cookies, el problema es de caché, esto depende mucho del servidor donde tienes alojado tu sitio, normalmente el navegador al cargar una pagina por primer vez la guarda en caché pero debe luego revalidar con el servidor si ha cambiado o no, a través de unos encabezados especiales como el Etag, si no lo maneja tu servidor solo te queda usar en el head etiquetas meta para modificar los valores cache-control(max-age) y expires, pero no te aseguro que vaya a funcionar

Comment: Hola @JonnathanQ pues esas etiquetas son las que quería yo saber cual son, como escribirlas y donde ponerlas exactamente en el `head` . Si me das alguna idea se agradecería

Comment: @gemita exactamente como mencionas se colocan dentro del tag head, also asi: **<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=300" />** o **<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Mon, 09 Mar 2018 23:59:59 GMT" />** fíjate que para el primer caso es el tiempo en segundos, para el segundo caso se maneja la fecha de expiración en formato RFC 1123

Answer (score 7):

El código proporcionado es funcional siempre y cuando el javascript lo cargues o ejecutes luego de que el div "cookies" sea creado de lo contrario la línea

```
document.getElementById("cookies").style.display = "block";
```

dará un error pues el elemento con ID "cookies" no existe aún en el DOM

para manejo de cookies las funciones que usas están bien, para mayor compatibilidad sugiero la libreria de Mozilla que la podes encontrar aqui:
https://github.com/madmurphy/cookies.js

El parámetro expires está siendo puesto por la funcion setCookie (toma una cantidad de días y se los suma a la fecha actual)

```
function setCookie(c_name, value, exdays) {
```

en resumen el código debería quedar asi:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<title>cokies</title>
<style>
#cookies {
    background-color: #333;
    display:none;
    position:fixed;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    padding-bottom:60px;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    min-height:40px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color:#fff;
    z-index:99999;
}

.inner {
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    padding-left:5px;
    font-family:verdana;
    font-size:12px;
    top:30%;
}

.inner a.ok {padding:4px;color:#00ff2e;text-decoration:none;}
.inner a.info {padding-left:5px;text-decoration:none;color:#faff00;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="cookies">
   <div class="inner">
  Esta web utiliza cookies como datos estad&iacute;sticos de su navegaci&oacute;
  Si contin&uacute;a navegando consideramos que acepta el uso de cookies.
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="ok" onclick="PonerCookie();">
    <b>OK</b>
  </a> |
  <a href="politica-cookies.html" target="_blank" class="info">M&aacute;s informaci&oacute;n</a>
</div>
</div>
</body>
<script>
function getCookie(c_name) {
  var c_value = document.cookie;
  var c_start = c_value.indexOf(" " + c_name + "=");
  if (c_start == -1) {
    c_start = c_value.indexOf(c_name + "=");
  }
  if (c_start == -1) {
    c_value = null;
  } else {
    c_start = c_value.indexOf("=", c_start) + 1;
    var c_end = c_value.indexOf(";", c_start);
    if (c_end == -1) {
      c_end = c_value.length;
    }
    c_value = unescape(c_value.substring(c_start, c_end));
  }
  return c_value;
}

function setCookie(c_name, value, exdays) {
  var exdate = new Date();
  exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
  var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
  document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

if (getCookie('tiendaaviso') != "1") {
  document.getElementById("cookies").style.display = "block";
}
function PonerCookie() {
  setCookie('tiendaaviso', '1', 365);
  document.getElementById("cookies").style.display = "none";
}
</script>
</html>
```

Nótese que el javascript está siendo cargado **después** de que aparece

```
<div id="cookies">
```

en el html.

**Edit:** Cómo agregar el aviso de cookies a mi web.

> (o como romper todo en 3 pasos si no hago copia de los archivos)

Para agregar este código a tu web, primero deberás averiguar cual es el archivo de la página principal.
Los nombres más comunes son (ordenados de mas común a mas raro):

- index.html
- index.htm
- index.php
- default.html
- default.htm
- index.shtml
- index.php5
- index.php4
- index.php3
- index.cgi
- home.html
- home.htm
- Index.html
- Index.htm
- Index.shtml
- Index.php
- Index.cgi
- Default.html
- Default.htm
- Home.html
- Home.htm
- placeholder.html

**Nota:** en algunos servidores la primer letra en mayúsculas es importante por eso aparecen repetidos algunos.

Una vez localizado el archivo hay que:

- descargarlo
- hacer una copia por si nos liamos y se rompe todo
- abrirlo en un editor de texto

... y buscar la línea donde dice:

```
</head>
```

que puede estar cerca o pegada a la linea que diga

```
<body>
```

Ahora bien por encima de `</head>` **y sin reemplazar nada de lo que ya hay**

Pegas esta parte del código:

```
<style>
#cookies {
    background-color: #333;
    display:none;
    position:fixed;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    padding-bottom:60px;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    min-height:40px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color:#fff;
    z-index:99999;
}

.inner {
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    padding-left:5px;
    font-family:verdana;
    font-size:12px;
    top:30%;
}

.inner a.ok {padding:4px;color:#00ff2e;text-decoration:none;}
.inner a.info {padding-left:5px;text-decoration:none;color:#faff00;}
</style>
```

Luego buscas una linea que diga:

```
</body>
```

**Nota:** suele estar al final del archivo

Aquí vamos a agregar una primera parte por encima y otra por debajo

**A** por arriba

```
<div id="cookies">
   <div class="inner">
  Esta web utiliza cookies como datos estad&iacute;sticos de su navegaci&oacute;
  Si contin&uacute;a navegando consideramos que acepta el uso de cookies.
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="ok" onclick="PonerCookie();">
    <b>OK</b>
  </a> |
  <a href="politica-cookies.html" 
     target="_blank" class="info">M&aacute;s informaci&oacute;n</a>
 </div>
 </div>
```

**B** Por debajo:

```
<script>
function getCookie(c_name) {
  var c_value = document.cookie;
  var c_start = c_value.indexOf(" " + c_name + "=");
  if (c_start == -1) {
    c_start = c_value.indexOf(c_name + "=");
  }
  if (c_start == -1) {
    c_value = null;
  } else {
    c_start = c_value.indexOf("=", c_start) + 1;
    var c_end = c_value.indexOf(";", c_start);
    if (c_end == -1) {
      c_end = c_value.length;
    }
    c_value = unescape(c_value.substring(c_start, c_end));
  }
  return c_value;
}

function setCookie(c_name, value, exdays) {
  var exdate = new Date();
  exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
  var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
  document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

if (getCookie('tiendaaviso') != "1") {
  document.getElementById("cookies").style.display = "block";
}
function PonerCookie() {
  setCookie('tiendaaviso', '1', 365);
  document.getElementById("cookies").style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias alo Malbarez
Ha sido la mejor explicación que he encontrado. Siempre cargaba nuevamente el banner.

Answer (score 2):

Ademas de lo ya expuesto por **@alo Malbarez**, es importante hacer notar que debes activar las `cookies` en tu navegador de lo contrario producirá un efecto al planteado en tu pregunta.

### Para activar las cookies:

**en Chrome:**

1. En tu computadora, abre Chrome.
2. En la parte superior derecha, haz clic en (los 3 puntos) y luego Configuración.
3. En la parte inferior, haz clic en Configuración avanzada.
4. En la sección "Privacidad y seguridad", haz clic en Configuración de contenido.
5. Haz clic en Cookies.
6. Activa o desactiva Permitir que todos los sitios guarden y lean datos de cookies.

**en Firefox:**

1. Las ultimas versiones de firefox no permiten desactivar las cookies :((